# Why is `git show` indentation inconsistent?

Tags: git

When I execute *git show* I'm seeing inconsistent indentation. The file uses a mix of "8-space" tabs and spaces, and I've run *git config core.pager 'less -x8'*. The source file appears as expected, and most of the output of *git show* is as I expect, but this one:

```
+convert_size_by_transform_scale(int32_t *width_out, int32_t *height_out,
+                               int32_t width, int32_t height,
+                               uint32_t transform,
+                               int32_t scale)
```

Lines 2-4 above should appear with one more space of indentation. The source file itself appears as:

```
convert_size_by_transform_scale(int32_t *width_out, int32_t *height_out,
                                int32_t width, int32_t height,
                                uint32_t transform,
                                int32_t scale)
```

And, again, other lines in the output of *git show* appear correctly indented. Running *less* on the file also displays the correct indentation. So what's up with those few lines that appear mis-indented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tab character advances the cursor to the next tab stop. In your case, your indented lines are at exactly 32 columns (or 4 tabs). That holds true whether we put a `+` in column 1 or not.

In other words, the rendering works like this:

- column 1 `TAB`: move to column 9
- column 9 `TAB`: move to column 17
- column 17 `TAB`: move to column 25
- column 25 `TAB`: move to column 33
- (print the rest of the line...)

In the lines prefixed with `+`, it does this:

- column 1 `+`: print a `+`
- column 2 `TAB`: move to column 9
- column 9 `TAB`: move to column 17
- column 17 `TAB`: move to column 25
- column 25 `TAB`: move to column 33
- (print the rest of the line...)

The first line, of course, contains no tabs. So when we add a `+` in column 1, everything is shifted to the right by one position. Since the same is not true of the indented lines, they are no longer consistent with the first line.

It is the presence of the leading `+` character that shifts things like this. That's why `less` does not show this - it is not giving you a diff, so the `+` is not there.

There's not much you can do about this except use spaces to ident instead of using tabs.